# Calling clear on an STL container of STL containers

Tags: c++, stl

I am using

`std::vector<std::vector<int>> S;` but the problem can apply to any additional dimension of nesting as well.

To clear content from `S`, is it sufficient from an efficiency/memory point of view to call `S.clear();` or should one first `clear` the stored container, in this case `std::vector<int>` and then `S.clear();` as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator iter;
for (iter = S.begin(); iter != S.end(); iter++) {
    iter->clear();
}
S.clear();
```

Comment: Do the simpler thing.  You will not code something more efficient than `s.clear()`.

Comment: `clear()` does not deallocate memory. So I believe `S.clear()` is enough.

Comment: @DeiDei In this case it will deallocate memory. The inner vectors will be destroyed which necessarily will release their memory (if they had any allocated). Only the outer most vector's capacity will remain untouched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `clear()` on the nested vector(s) is unneeded.  When you call `clear()` on the outermost vector it will destroy each element in the vector.  This will in turn destroy any nested vectors.

`std::vector` is an RAII type, so as long as you are storing an RAII type in it, it will do the right thing, since the types clean up after themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `clear` on the outermost container. The destructor of the contained containers will clean up their space automatically. The only thing to watch out for is if somewhere down the nesting you have owning raw-pointers. If you have code that does that just change it to use any kind of smart owning pointer, owning the object by value, or another level of container nesting instead of a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure you really release the memory, you may want to do something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>().swap(S);
```